# Ambiguous use of subscript error while trying to build app on an actual device

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, string

I am trying to build my app on a real device (iPhone 7 plus). My application runs just fine on the simulator, but when i try to build it on a real device it gives me 2 "Ambiguous use of subscript errors".

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/news/search?q=\(feedsArray[i])&count=3&mkt=en-in")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.setValue("MY SUBSCRIPTION KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")

        Alamofire.request(request as URLRequest).responseJSON {response in

            if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]{


                if let value = json["value"]{

                    //
                    print("json \(json)")

                    for j in 0..<value.count{

                        let items = value[j] as! [String: AnyObject]

                        let name = items["name"] as! String

                        let url = items["url"] as! String



                        let description = items["description"] as! String

                        let datePublished = items["datePublished"] as! String

                        let dateAndTime = datePublished.replacingOccurrences(of: "T", with: " ")
```

I am having the error in the line

```
     let items = value[j] as! [String: AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `json["value"]` is `Dictionary`, thats why you got error when you try to subscript it with `value[j]`, you might want to cast it to `Array` if you want to subscript it like

`if let value = json["value"] as! [[String: Any]]`

Comment: @NiravD I also said so?

Comment: Thanks for the input